# "the following need" vs "the following needs"

Tags: grammatical-number, american-english, british-english

I understand that *need* is used for plural subjects while *needs* is for singular subjects.
However, if the sentence were simply `The following ___ to be done by tomorrow` , would it be *need* or *needs*

Edit:
I understand that without information of what "The following" is, it's hard to decide.
This is the context:

> The following need to be completed by noon:
>
> 1. Enlisting the new requirements
> 2. Calling up customers to verify their
>      requirements
> 3. Providing a more inclusive growth plan

Comment: So, what is "the following"?

Comment: The very first sentence of your question answers it -- If you have multiple objects or actions that ***need*** to be done by tomorrow, or a singular object or action that ***needs*** to be done by tomorrow... That's dependent on how many objects or actions make up "the following"...

Comment: *The following [things] need to be done by noon: a, b, c,...*

Comment: On the other hand, *the following [collection] needs to be done by noon: a, b, c, ...*.

Comment: Note to reviewers: I voted to keep this question open - it's an interesting question about whether there is a bias in the OP's context towards singular or plural agreement when the subject is absent (*cf* [A.H's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/411244/142322)).

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer would be contingent on, the absent subject that the phrase '*the following*' is referring to.

Comment: So, if the subject were a list with multiple items, would it be need? (ref: edit to the question)

Comment: Yes, I would also go with 'need'.

Comment: @glowinthedark It depends on whether you take the 'absent subject' to be *multiple* items or a *single* aggregation.